# How to make an aggregate function of MongoDB case insensitive?

Tags: c#, mongodb-.net-driver

```
public async Task<IEnumerable<Person>> GetPersonDetailsByEmailsAsync(IEnumerable<string> emails)
        {
            var pipeline = BuildQueryToFetchWithGroupDetails(
                new[] {
                    new BsonDocument {
                        {
                            "$match",
                            new BsonDocument {
                                {
                                     "email",
                                     new BsonDocument {
                                        {
                                            "$in",
                                            new BsonArray(emails)
                                        }
                                     }
                                }
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            );
            return await _personDetailsCollection.Aggregate<Person>(pipeline).ToListAsync();
        }
```

Currently, this search is case sensitive, how can I make it case insensitive?

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Since, this code is a C# code I added it in the title

Comment: I meant that your question asks to make the search insensitive to case, but the title asked how to make it case sensitive. I fixed it for you.

Comment: Oh, is it? Sorry, my bad.

Comment: I've never done this as I opted to normalise e-mails before saving them to Mongo, but I think you can make a case-insensitive index and use that to query your collection.

Comment: I gave it a thought, but I'm working on an enhancement project and its kind of expected for me not to touch the DB. So, I'm trying to find the best way to do it on the code itself